# Invalid index type for class created with attrs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-attrs

I'm currently rewriting a program, where I take two older scripts and combine them to one. I reuse most of the code and I also use `mypy` for type checking in the new version.

What always comes up is a mypy error that have an invalid index type when trying to access an attribute from a class which I created with `attrs`.

```py
# classes.py
@attrs(on_setattr=_validate_dict)
class Config:
    defaults = attrib(
        default=Factory(dict),
        validator=_validate_dict)
    target = attrib(
        default=Factory(dict),
        validator=_validate_dict)
    source = attrib(
        default=Factory(dict),
        validator=_validate_dict)
    etl = attrib(
        default=Factory(dict),
        validator=_validate_dict)

# main.py
config = Config()
data = {
    'foo':'bar'
}
config.defaults.update(data)
# can also be
# config.default = data
# or
# setattr(
#     self,
#     defaults,
#     {x: y for (x, y) in data.items()}
# )

a = config.defaults['foo']
b = config.defaults.get('foo')
```

In both cases I get the message:
`Invalid index type "str" for "Dict[_KT, _VT]"; expected type "_KT"`

The only way I can skip this is to manually add `# type: ingore` at the end of the line. Either I don't use the class correctly or I oversee something.

Anyone out there having a hint for me? Thx in advance.

Comment: I cannot run your example to verify, but something seems to confuse mypy. I don't think it actually looks at the factory's type, so I suspect, that it assumes that the type of `defaults` is the return value of `attrib`. Try adding `type=dict` to the attrib call?

Comment: Sorry, that I wasn't able to post all the code since it also contains internals and maybe some lines which are not relevant. Anyway, your tip by adding the type to attrib seems to work, many thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

To make it an official answer:

The code doesn't define types for the attributes (either using annotations or the `type` argument). Therefore `mypy` looks at the type of the return value of `attr.ib` which doesn't make any sense at all (it's actually removed by the `@attr.s` decorator when it's done).

Arguably it would be better, if mypy handled this case more smoothly.